# Moving Gmap under Div

Tags: javascript, css

The point is this:
[image]

I need to move gmap under div main ( it has 3 hole ..) ...
Can anyone suggest some solution?
Thanks!

Comment: Care to elaborate? How are you making the "holes"?

Comment: I still don't know!!!maybe css??

Answer (score 1):

Just use CSS on the div:
position: absolute
top: x px
left: x px

More on position property: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_position.asp